# How to auto upload google sheets data with time driven trigger?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xmlhttprequest

I want to upload google sheets data by converting it to JSON and uploading it with post method to my other website how should I do it?

I am trying to use ajax request but can't figure it out properly. If I can use XMLHttpRequest I might figure it out but I don't know how to do it in Google Apps Scripts.

Comment: Please share minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We can't picture your sample data and your expected output. If also possible share the current script you are using. Posts with complete detail and can be replicated easily are more likely to get answered

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvinience but luckily i found the solution by the answer given below by @ValLeNain
I was using AJAX instead i should have used UrlFetchApp which worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normally show what you have tried so far so we can correct you code if needed.

But, if you're really lost and looking for a direction, what you probably want to do is

1. [Setup a time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) (for every minute, every day, whatever)
2. Use the `SpreadsheetApp` service ([doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)) to retrieve your sheets data with Apps Script (server-side)
3. Use the `UrlFetchApp` service ([doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)) to make a POST request to your website

Since it's a server to server request, there is no ajax in here.

Comment: Thanks bruh  that UrlFetchApp thing helped me and i was successfully abled to do my work. i didn't know the UrlFetchApp thing and instead i was trying to use ajax(XMLHttpRequest) which did not work but this worked like a charm